# Determining expected value of two Gaussian variables given their sum

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value

You are given two pairwise independent Gaussian random variables, $X$ and $Y$. Suppose $X$ ~ $N(m_1, v_1)$ and $Y$ ~ $N(m_2, v_2)$. Suppose you know X+Y = n. What is the expected value of Y condition on this?

I ran a simulation, thought about it a little bit, and pieced eventually pieced together that $Y = (n-m_1) - (n-m_1-m_2)*(v_1) / (v_1+v_2)$.

With that said, I don't have a clue how to prove this. How would I go about proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y$ and $X+Y$ are jointly normally distributed.

$Var(Y)=v_2$

$Var(X+Y)=v_1+v_2$

$Cov(Y,X+Y)=v_2$

$$\begin{bmatrix}Y\\X+Y \end{bmatrix}\sim N\left(\begin{bmatrix}m_2 \\ m_1+m_2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} v_2 & v_2 \\ v_2 & v_1+v_2\end{bmatrix} \right)$$

Now, we just have to compute the [marginal distribution of the Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution):

\begin{align}E[Y|X+Y=n]&=m_2+Cov(Y,X+Y)\cdot Var(X+Y)^{-1}\cdot (n-m_1-m_2) \\&=m_2+\frac{v_2}{v_1+v_2}(n-m_1-m_2)\\
&=\frac{v_2}{v_1+v_2}(n-m_1)+\frac{v_1}{v_1+v_2}(m_2)\end{align}

Comment: thanks, let me examine.

Comment: I think the formula matches now.